# Add custom class to all URLs on entire site

Tags: functions

I have a mobile touch script which uses the class "tapover". Now I want to insert it to all URL links on my entire site. How do I do that?

Update:

```
function strapboot_enable_mobile_touch() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Use class "tapover" in your link to implement this
        $(&#39;a.taphover&#39;).on(&quot;touchstart&quot;, function (e) {
            &#39;use strict&#39;; //satisfy code inspectors
            var link = $(this); //preselect the link
            if (link.hasClass(&#39;hover&#39;)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                link.addClass(&#39;hover&#39;);
                $(&#39;a.taphover&#39;).not(this).removeClass(&#39;hover&#39;);
                e.preventDefault();
                return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent return points
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php }
add_action('wp_footer', 'strapboot_enable_mobile_touch');
```

The problem is I have to manually add the class to all links. Can there be a way to implement this script to all link URL?

Updated: Here's is what I have come up with by changing nofollow plugin:

```
add_filter ( 'wp_insert_post_data' , 'add_mobile_touch_link', 99);
function add_mobile_touch_link ( $post ) {
$post = str_ireplace("<a href", "<a class=\"tapover\" href", $post);
return $post;
}
```

Now it does add the class "tapover" in the post content area, but not in header, footer and sidebar. Kindly help!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your work to date as an EDIT to your question and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you mean all links in your site content only? I assume you don't intend to use this for links in your menus, is that correct? Also, please clarify if this is a one-off fix or if the script should run on new links too.

Comment: what I exactly want is to insert automatically the class "tapover" in all links new or old from header to footer.
Example: 
    <a href="#any" class="tapover- //should come here automatically">Link</a>

Comment: it looks like you copied and pasted that script from somewhere, the quotes are all html entities instead of proper quotes, you need to change `&#39;` to `'`